# Geopandas: Color specific clusters in existing figure from shapefile

Tags: python, geopandas

I have plotted a figure using a shapefile through a function using geopandas, it represents Germany with each federal state represented as a cluster. Now I would like to color the region with highest electricity production and the one with the lowest, both with different colors.
I am new to geopandas and couldn't find an answer, I guess I have to create a subplot but I'm not sure? How can I select and color each cluster? (I already determined the name and electricity production of the max and min cluster).

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The type of plot you are trying to create is called [Choropleth Maps](https://geopandas.org/docs/user_guide/mapping.html). Create a data frame with the name of the federal state,  electricity production of the max and min cluster, and the geometry of the state extracted from the shapefile. Doing this will create only 2 states with different colors, but if you want the map of Germany also, then you need to include the geometry of all the states and set their electricity to NaN.

Then you can call the plot() on the data frame with column='electricity_production'

```
df.head()
>> name, electricity_production, geometry
   'cluster1', max/min,  MULTIPOLYGON(((...
   'cluster2', max/min. POLYGON((..

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
df.plot(column='electricity_production', ax=ax, legend=True)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I think I had an error in reasoning and thought I wouldn't have to make a new dataframe, I will try as you suggested!